# Electronic resources for learning Z/OS assembler?

Tags: mainframe, assembly, zos

This is a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706426/teaching-my-self-z-os-assembler) question. I'm totally blind so printed books aren't an option. All the recommended books appear to have been published before electronic publishing got started. I've been able to learn the very basics but would like something between here's what a register is, and the IBM reference material. Searching the normal places like Safari Books Online has come up dry.

Comment: Do this have the information you need ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706426/teaching-my-self-z-os-assembler

Answer (score 1):

[1]: http://ibmmainframes.com/post-8918.html Here is a post from a forum which has  loads of links to lots of online resources. It is an answer to a questions very similar to yours.

The author recommends looking at www.cbttape.org/ if you want to learn from examples. I don't do much assmbler on the mainframe but have found CBT tape an invaluable resource for learning about the mainframe and its tools.